# How can I foreach a sum query using blade in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

This is my sum query, It actually sums up the number of units and a subject price of a specific student.

```
$subjects = DB::table('subjects')
            ->join('subjectblocking', 'subjects.subjectcode', '=', 'subjectblocking.subjectcode')
            ->join('grades', 'subjectblocking.blockcode', '=', 'grades.blockcode')
            ->select('subjects.numofunit as total_units','subjects.price as total_tuition')

            ->orWhere(function($query)
            {
                $query->where('grades.studentid', '=', '2013-F0218')
                        ->where('sem', '=', '1')
                        ->where('sy', '=', '2013-2014');
            })
            ->sum('subjects.numofunit','subjects.price');


    return View::make('users.assessment')->with('subjects', $subjects);
```

This is how I foreach it in blade

```
@foreach ($subjects as $subject)
                {
                <tr>
                <td>{{$subject->total_units}}</td>
                <td>{{$subject->total_tuition}}</td>
                </tr>        
                }
            @endforeach
```

However it tells me that

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: This means that there is an error in your query.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer well ofc. but how can i foreach a sum in blade?

Comment: There's no problem with foreach. The problem is in your query. $subjects is false instead of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how aggregate methods work in `Query\Builder`. Check this:

```
DB::table('a_table')
  ->sum('a_field'); // returns string, eg. '555'
  // or
  ->count('a_field'); // returns int, eg. 333
```

The same goes for all aggregate methods.

In order to achieve what you want, you need `selectRaw` (`DB::raw`) and obviously a `groupBy` clause:

```
DB::table(..)
   ->selectRaw('sum(a_field) as sum, sum(another_field) as another_sum')
   ->groupBy('yet_another_field')
   ->get();
```